# Get attributes from last block created

Tags: block-editor

Is there a way to get the attributes or clientId from a block recently created or inserted in editor?

Exist any js event for that?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do that needs this? And are you trying to do it in a block? Sidebar plugin?

Comment: Hi, I'm doing an accordion block, so each item must have an unique ID, so when I duplicate some item, this copy the ID, so I want change this ID after element creation.

Comment: client IDs are already unique, when you duplicate a block the two blocks have different client IDs. This means you already have all the tools needed to do this by doing `if ( myblocksIDattribute != myblocksClientID ) { it changed! }`

Comment: also you can set the `id=""` part from the block ID in PHP and eliminate all of the javascript, or better yet, set it via a `data` attribute and then your users can pick any `id` they want and it will _always_ work, even if they mess with the HTML markup

Comment: My question is. when a block is duplicated through the editor, I wonder if there is a way to modify the attributes of the copy on the fly? As example: set the value anchor attribute. Is there a trigger that allows me to modify the copied instance of the block

Comment: as I mentioned, when a block is duplicated its block ID changes, and you can check for this in the edit component which is immediately rendered